# Tick labels displacement when using line chart with negative data

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to generate a line chart, but part of my values are negative ones. The chart is rendered correctly, but the tick labels on the X axis are displaced. It seems that by default they're placed few pixels below X=0.

```
$objWorksheet->fromArray(
        array(
                array('',       2010,   2011,   2012),
                array('Q1',   12,   15,         21),
                array('Q2',   -20,   73,         86),
                array('Q3',   -50,   61,         69),
                array('Q4',   30,   32,         0),
        )
);
```

Result:

[image: wrong tick labels position]

Using OpenOffice when I'm editing the chart, I can right click on the X=0 line => Format Axis => Positioning => Labels, and by default the generated chart have selected 'Near axis'. When I change this to 'Outside start' for example, the result is:

[image: wanna be labels position]

How can this be done using PHPExcel?

Comment: I'm still unable to resolve that issue. Looked at the source code of PHPExcel and in documentation, but could not find anything related. Is this functionality even existing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved my question. If anyone is experiencing the same bug, applying the following fix until this becomes configurable solves the problem:

In file `Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php`, function `_writeCatAx`, line `506` in my revision. Right after `$objWriter->startElement('c:tickLblPos');` I had line `$objWriter->writeAttribute('val', "nextTo");`.

The fix is changing `nextTo` to `low`.

PHPExcel is a great piece of software, but having this kind of stuff configurable is a must.

Comment: this solution doesn't work with me, can you share a sample of your code

Comment: The version this answer works with is 1.8.0. Check it out.

Comment: That line needs to be changed from `nextTo` to `low` - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/992aee683ac0e9f8acfa12a52a4f3cc19a9e3808/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php#L506